# How do i remove firebug console from other browsers?

Tags: firefox, firebug

I have developed my site with Firefox and firebug plugin, but when i deploy it to other browsers (IE/Chrome), the console window appears at the bottom of the screen(very annoying).

How can i disable this? and why is it appearing?

gath

Answer (score 7):

Does your site include script tags/... that load [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html)? If so, remove them and firebug shouldn't show up anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you remove all the [console commands](http://getfirebug.com/console.html) in your code. I don't know if this is the reason in your case but it can cause errors in other browsers.